# Guess correct stable memory/RAM CAS?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, memory-timings, cas

I have several APACER 8GB UNB PC3-12800 CL11 but i could not find any document about correct CAS .

Usually the CAS written on piece of paper which attached to RAM . Motherboard bios shows the part number of DIMMs are 78.c1get.9l10c and chipset NO is AM5D6008BEQSCK

The bios itself shows 11-11-11-28 as default value but it is not correct because memtest86 shows millions of error after 1 hour ~43% . I tried 11-11-11-31 which found from http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM3+/M5A99FX_PRO_R20/M5_R20_Series_DRAM_QVL_1127.pdf which similar to my RAMs chip number except one Q letter but again memtest shows errors

Edit 1 : I have 5 motherboards with same part no . each one has 4 slots with this kind of ram with the same error . Even when i put DIMMs just one by one and test , same error appears .

[image] [image] .

Comment: If Memtest shows millions of errors at the default timings, have you considered that the memory might be bad?

Comment: Not necessarily. I have such experience . Usually most people do ram test for about 10~15 minutes which mine does not show any errors . It shows errors after ~1 hours which related to very complex testings .